# How can I prohibit access to all sites in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, security, access-control

How can I prohibit access to all sites in Google Chrome, except for one or two sites?

Comment: This is better done within your router or via 3rd party software as it is not the browsers job to filter traffic.

Comment: You may also want to look at the various questions tagged [parental controls](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/parental-controls)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not too nice, but if you can somehow ensure folks won't change the settings:

- Make your internet settings use a non-existing proxy server (like "localhost");
- Add exceptions for the few sites you want to allow.

Comment: I like this idea. I was trying to figure out a way to prevent my young kids from browsing too deep into the web. I know they don't know how to change the settings yet.

Comment: *yet*..., @Mike ;-) Or know how to use a different browser?

Comment: The proxy is all OS based..the browsers goal is not filtering traffic. If you modify the proxy settings in Chrome it is nothing more then a redirect to the OS based proxy settings.

Comment: True, @Aaron. Firefox allows for its own settings (or none, or the system wide settings), so Firefox could use different settings than the fake settings for Chrome (and IE). Still, I agree very much: *not too nice...*

Comment: I should clarify, on my Chrome OS laptop. Yes, I realize that they could work around it.

Answer (score 5):

[OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) has web content filtering, even in the free version. The free version supports up to 25 blacklist/whitelist items. As an extra, you'll get phishing and botnet protection and your web browsing may also receive some extra speed!

Answer (score 0):

Back these days, I used [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/):

> Privoxy is a non-caching web proxy with advanced filtering capabilities for enhancing privacy, modifying web page data and HTTP headers, controlling access, and removing ads and other obnoxious Internet junk. Privoxy has a flexible configuration and can be customized to suit individual needs and tastes. It has application for both stand-alone systems and multi-user networks.